# Will Fullcalendar still work when Google XML feeds are shutdown Nov 17, 2015?

Tags: fullcalendar

Google will no longer provide xml feeds to calendars on Nov 17 2015
https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285065?p=xml_deprecation&rd=1

How will this effect Fullcalendar?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked from Google's support forum.

Answer (score 0):

i would also like to know the answer to this and dont think it belongs on the google forum. google announced the following:

> Important announcement about XML feeds in Google Calendar
>   Because of low usage, and in an effort to streamline our services, from 18 November 2015, XML feeds will no longer be available in Google Calendar. You're getting this message because you're currently viewing or sharing a link to one or more of your calendars using an XML feed.
>
> We apologise for any inconvenience caused. Google Calendar will continue to support three ways of viewing your calendars in other applications or on websites. You can:
>
> Access your calendar in other applications, such as Microsoft Outlook or Apple Calendar, using iCal.
>   Embed your calendar in your website or blog using HTML.
>   Use the Google Calendar API to display, create and modify calendar events if you're a developer.
>   Finally, you can always view and manage your calendars using the Google Calendar app for Android, iPhone or on the web.
>   - The Calendar team"

is fullcalendar using an XML feed is the question? it is definitely using the API but there is also reference to json content...

if someone could shed some light on this it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you simply add `?alt=json` to the xml feed, you will get a JSON feed. Will that be an option for folks ? I am consuming that feed right now in my app and it works for me.

Comment: Sweet. Will give that a try.